# Kotlin Annotation: Type mismatch: inferred type is java.lang.Class<foo> but java.lang.Class<out jet.Annotation> was expected

Tags: kotlin

Given the following Kotlin Annotation:

```
public Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME) annotation class foo(val text : String)
```

and the following code to check if a class is annotated by above annotation:

```
if (javaClass<Bar>().isAnnotationPresent(javaClass<foo>())) {
    // do something here.
}
```

If the annotation class (`foo`) and the code which is using it were located in the same module (maven artifact), the code can compile and run without any issue.

But, if I separate them into different modules, the following compile error happens:

> Kotlin: Type mismatch: inferred type is java.lang.Class but
>   java.lang.Class was expected

Any idea what could be the issue?

Comment: Apparently this is a bug. I've created a ticket for it here: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-3534

Comment: I think this issue is no longer an issue.  Bugs were closed as "cannot reproduce" in later versions.

Answer (score 1):

Problem seems to be marked as fixed. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-3197 This was a bug.